# C++ passing array using reference operator

Tags: c++, arrays, pass-by-reference

I have a question about passing array with reference operator. I want to write code that pass array using reference operator. Then I tried

```
void swap(int &testarray[3]){
 // code
}
```

It gives me error. It says,

```
/main.cpp:5: error: declaration of 'testarray' as array of references
```

However when changed my code with

```
void swap(int (&testarray)[3]){
  // code
  }
```

It runs properly. Only difference is having bracket.

Why it needs bracket and what is the difference between int (&testarray)[3] and int &testarray[3]

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Why would you want to pass an array by reference?

Comment: @Cornstalks Why wouldn't you want to pass an array by reference? @burakim: Since you've tagged this C++11, you could switch to `std::array<int, 3>` and avoid such vagaries of C declarator syntax.

Comment: @Praetorian: because arrays can't be assigned to, and already decay to pointers.

Comment: @Cornstalks I don't see how not being assignable is relevant, you can still assign to individual elements. And the decaying to pointer loses size information, which makes it inconvenient for most use cases.

Comment: By passing by reference, you may use `std::end(testarray)`

Comment: @Praetorian: You lose size information when passing an array to a function, regardless of whether or not you use a reference. I don't see any benefit of passing an array by reference to a function. Normally, you pass by reference if the object is large (which isn't relevant as the array decays to a pointer), or if you want to modify the object (which you can't do with arrays). Yes, you can modify the elements of an array, but you can't modify the array itself.

Comment: @Cornstalks You're mistaken, the syntax above preserves size information. And I don't know what you mean by *modify the array itself*; yes, you can't reassign it to point to another array, or resize it, but a lot, if not most, use cases involve reading or writing the array elements rather than reassigning / resizing.

Comment: @Praetorian: Yeah, I was mistaken. I had a brain fart and thought you could pass a differently sized array to the function (i.e. pass an `int [4]` to the OP's `swap` function), but that's not even legal (with references). So the two use cases I can now think of passing by reference would be to 1) ensure the array/pointer isn't null, and 2) to enforce the argument to be an array type of the exact size.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`void foo(int &testarray[3])` is interpreted as `void foo((int &)testarray[3])` due to priority. And array of references are illegal.

Whereas `void foo(int (&testarray)[3])` is interpreted as you want. (reference of an array of 3 int).

`void foo(int testarray[3])` is equivalent to `void foo(int testarray[])`
which decays to `void foo(int *testarray)`. (int pointer).

Answer (score 0):

In fact this construction

```
int & testarray[3]
```

defines an array of references to integral objects. The C++ Standard  does not allow to define arrays of references to objects.